# How do I use the IPython kernel programmatic interface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I have the following code which should programmatically run a jupyter kernel.

Here's an example:

```
from jupyter_client import KernelManager
from queue import Empty
from jupyter_client.blocking import BlockingKernelClient

# maybe the kernel needs time to boot up?
km = KernelManager(kernel_name="python3")
client = km.client()
client = km.blocking_client()
client.start_channels()

import time
time.sleep(1)

msg_id = client.execute("???")
print(msg_id)

while True:
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print("sleeping ...")
    try:
      reply = client.get_shell_msg(timeout=1)
      print("reply")
      print(reply)
      if reply['parent_header']['msg_id'] == msg_id:
        if reply['content']['status'] == 'error':
          print({"error_type": "failed_to_execute", 'error': '\n'.join(reply['content']['traceback'])})
        break
    except Empty:
      print("shell_empty")
      # pass
 
    try:
      iopub_msg = client.get_iopub_msg(timeout=1)
      print("iopub_msg")
      print(iopub_msg)
      break
    except Empty:
      print("iopub_empty")
```

but in practice, I just get a message id, and then both channels just return empty forever. What am I doing wrong?